# STM32F746 - DISCO I2C HAL_TIMEOUT

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, hal-library

I am attempting to implement I2C interface on the STM32F7-Discovery Board using the a VEML 6070 UV light sensor (https://www.vishay.com/docs/84277/veml6070.pdf).

The 7-bit slave address for the device is 0x38. The addresses for data access are 0x71(LSB) and 0x73(MSB)

I am not able to write or read any data from the master. When I check the HAL_Status it returns HAL_Timeout.

Some of my code is shown below:

EDIT:

```
void VEML6070_Init(void){

char data[1];

HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0x18<<1, data, 1, 150); 

data[0] = 0x06;

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, data, 1, 150);

}

int main(void)  {  
 unsigned int rawUV;
 char lcd_buf[5]
 uint8_t address[1];
 uint8_t MSBdata[1];
 uint8_t LSBdata[1];
 SystemClock_Config();
 MX_I2C1_Init();
 MX_GPIO_Init();

 VEML6070_Init();

 address[0] = 0x02;

 HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, 0x70, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, address, 1, 150)

 HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, 0x73, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, MSBdata, 1, 150)

 HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, 0x71, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, LSBdata, 1, 150)

 rawUV = MSBdata[0]<<8 | LSBdata[0];
 sprintf(lcd_buf, "%d ", rawUV);
 //GLCD_DrawString (0, 7*24, lcd_buf);
}
```

Does anybody have experience of implementing I2C with the STM32F7 boards, and if so are you able to shed any light on why I may be getting 'HAL_TIMEOUT'?
Is it a case of me using the wrong register addresses, or is it something more complex?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have now altered the code to use the correct protocol, but I am still finding a 'HAL_TIMEOUT'.

```
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, address, 1, 150);

HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0x39<<1, MSBdata, 1, 150);

HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, LSBdata, 1, 150);
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You're probably at a point where it would be good to get a scope or logic analyzer on the signals and see what is happening, especially if you have a known working configuration (some off-the-shelf Arduino example sketch?) to compare to.  Even without a reference some problems like I/O pins not configured to the point where they toggle at all will be obvious, and others can be figured out with the help of a protocol decoder built into modern instruments, or carefully studying and manually interpreting the plot.  What's your pull-up resistor situation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a debugging question needing additional followup by the asker, but has been abandoned for years

Comment: Some suggestions which aren't going to fix your problem, but would be good practice: Get rid of those magic numbers. For example. What does 1 mean? And 150? Put meaningful defines in, you'll help yourself a lot in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is wrong. It is not register based to a single slave address so you can't use the Mem_Write and Mem_Read functions. What you have is there are three different slave addresses for single byte for command, MSB and LSB data.

Comment: Hi, thank for your response. Would the 'HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit' and 'HAL_I2C_Master_Receive' be the correct protocols?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I am still experiencing the problem.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I still haven't solved the issue. Do the protocols in my edit look correct now?

Comment: Maybe, but you don't say which of those operations times out, and you don't show if you have initialized the chip with the sequence found in datasheets and application notes before it responds correctly.

Comment: Both Transmit and Receive time out. I have an initialize function: 
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 0x18<<1, address, 1, 150); HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 0x38<<1, address, 1, 150); but again I'm unsure if this the correct way to to initialize the chip

Comment: That would depend on what value you send as data from the variable called "address" which has nothing to do with address by the way.

Comment: Yes sorry that variable shouldn't be called address. The value it holds for the Receive operation is just 0x00, and the value it holds for the Transmit operation is 0x06.

Comment: No because it is set to 0x02 to begin with, then 0x18 address is read and data from it overwrites the variable and then this value is written back to chip into command register. Or at least the code that I can see from your posts does.

Comment: I didn't include my initialisation code in my original post, I will edit it again to make this clearer. I based it on the section in the datasheet that indicates you have to clear the ack register by reading it first, and then write 0x06 to the write register.